# magetno2 magetique theme template monster No such entity with id = 57

Tags: magento2

I have deleted some products now website is not working(front end crash) showing code on front page

**No such entity with id = 57 in store_group  table my theme root category id is =57.**

**default store id is 19**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below method to your front-end is opening smoothly...

**In this situation please update root category id with 1. Its default root category id.**